# Automatic garbage collection is not happening

Tags: garbage-collection

My code is calling rest webservice. It will work as expected when the data is proper at server. But some time webservice  will return some wrong output due to some data issue ,it is returning old calls response to every calls which having data issue.  I am getting some false response when expected data is not found. I guess here automatic garbage collection is not happening.

Help is appreciated if anyone tells how I overcome this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think garbage collection is the problem you describe.  Eddy's caching suggestion sounds more likely.  If the problem is not that the data is cached by your browser or client code, it might be cached by the webservice.  You should give additional details about the webservice and clientside code technologies you are using, and perhaps some specific code that results in the incorrect data.

Comment: I guess it is webservice cache and It is Rest webservice. I  have used Apache wink client for the same. Am not setting any cache control techniques in my code. Will it help if I set no-cache in cache control?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your issue is at the client side? If you are calling your api from javascript i.e. jquery, you may want to disable cache, just a thinking

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    cache: false,
    ...
});
```

Comment: No it's not jquery, here call is happening from Java class